# Get the contents of a table row with a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick, html-table

I need to extract the details of each column in my table. For example, column "Name/Nr.".

- The table contains a number of addresses
- The very last column of each row has a button that lets a user choose a listed address.

**Problem:** My code only picks up the first `<td>` that has a class `nr`. How do I get this to work?

**Here's the jQuery bit:**

```
$(".use-address").click(function() {
    var id = $("#choose-address-table").find(".nr:first").text();
    $("#resultas").append(id); // Testing: append the contents of the td to a div
});
```

**Table:**

```
<table id="choose-address-table" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
            <th>Name/Nr.</th>
            <th>Street</th>
            <th>Town</th>
            <th>Postcode</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="nr"><span>50</span>
            </td>
            <td>Some Street 1</td>
            <td>Leeds</td>
            <td>L0 0XX</td>
            <td>United Kingdom</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="use-address" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="nr">49</td>
            <td>Some Street 2</td>
            <td>Lancaster</td>
            <td>L0 0XX</td>
            <td>United Kingdom</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="use-address" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 300, accepted):

The object of the exercise is to find the row that contains the information. When we get there, we can easily extract the required information.

## Answer

```
$(".use-address").click(function() {
    var $item = $(this).closest("tr")   // Finds the closest row <tr> 
                       .find(".nr")     // Gets a descendent with class="nr"
                       .text();         // Retrieves the text within <td>

    $("#resultas").append($item);       // Outputs the answer
});
```

**[VIEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UW38e/)**

Now let's focus on some frequently asked questions in such situations.

## **How to find the closest row?**

**Using `.closest()`:**

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
```

**Using `.parent()`:**

You can also move up the DOM tree using [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method. This is just an alternative that is sometimes used together with `.prev()` and `.next()`.

```
var $row = $(this).parent()             // Moves up from <button> to <td>
                  .parent();            // Moves up from <td> to <tr>
```

## **Getting all table cell `<td>` values**

So we have our `$row` and we would like to output table cell text:

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),       // Finds the closest row <tr> 
    $tds = $row.find("td");             // Finds all children <td> elements

$.each($tds, function() {               // Visits every single <td> element
    console.log($(this).text());        // Prints out the text within the <td>
});
```

**[VIEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CKEc6/1/)**

## **Getting a specific `<td>` value**

Similar to the previous one, however we can specify the index of the child `<td>` element.

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),        // Finds the closest row <tr> 
    $tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)"); // Finds the 2nd <td> element

$.each($tds, function() {                // Visits every single <td> element
    console.log($(this).text());         // Prints out the text within the <td>
});
```

**[VIEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T9uv7/)**

## **Useful methods**

- [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) - get the first element that matches the selector
- [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) - get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements
- [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) - get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements
- [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) - get the children of each element in the set of matched elements
- [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) - get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements
- [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) - get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements
- [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) - get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements
- [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) - get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements

Comment: What if I have a popup and I want to access a table from the page and delete the row? I tried one of the method, but it's not working for me :/

Comment: Can you prepare a jsFiddle?

Comment: Here I have similar issue whle handling dynamic ID values. Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772554/jquery-how-to-read-dynamically-generated-html-table-rows-td-value

Comment: Please help me with this question I have here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004056/how-to-retrieve-the-tr-data-on-the-same-row-within-gridview-using-jquery-modal-w (Thanks)

Comment: Mine is showing blank and not getting the text for some reason :/

Comment: Dunno how this answer is not much more upvoted. Excelent tips! Just wanted to add you can always get the column value like this after getting the specific row     $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)").html();  You will be getting the number 2 column. Cheers!

Comment: This is not working for me I have the same problem, need to read row data on click

Comment: Thanks a lot, how can we achieve the exact same thing using pure javascript ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works fine but how about if i want to use that id on another page?

Answer (score 13):

You need to change your code to find the row relative to the button which was clicked. Try this:

```
$(".use-address").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest("tr").find(".nr").text();
    $("#resultas").append(id);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FnDvL/)

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
$(".use-address").click(function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').find('td').each(function() {
        var textval = $(this).text(); // this will be the text of each <td>
   });
});
```

This will find the closest `tr` (going up through the DOM) of the currently clicked button and then loop each `td` - you might want to create a string / array with the values.

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/FnDvL/1/)

[**Getting the full address using an array example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/FnDvL/2/)

Answer (score 4):

```
function useAdress () { 
var id = $("#choose-address-table").find(".nr:first").text();
alert (id);
$("#resultas").append(id); // Testing: append the contents of the td to a div
};
```

then on your button:

```
onclick="useAdress()"
```

Comment: That has the same problem as the code in the question--it always gets the id from the first row in the table, regardless of which row's button was the one clicked.

Answer (score 3):

The selector `".nr:first"` is specifically looking for the first, and only the first, element having class `"nr"` within the selected table element. If you instead call `.find(".nr")` you will get all of the elements within the table having class `"nr"`. Once you have all of those elements, you could use the [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate over them. For example:

```
$(".use-address").click(function() {
    $("#choose-address-table").find(".nr").each(function(i, nrElt) {
        var id = nrElt.text();
        $("#resultas").append("<p>" + id + "</p>"); // Testing: append the contents of the td to a div
    });
});
```

However, that would get you *all* of the `td.nr` elements in the table, not just the one in the row that was clicked. To further limit your selection to the row containing the clicked button, use the [.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method, like so:

```
$(".use-address").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".nr").each(function(i, nrElt) {
        var id = nrElt.text();
        $("#resultas").append("<p>" + id + "</p>"); // Testing: append the contents of the td to a div
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Find element with id in row using jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("button").click(function() {
    //find content of different elements inside a row.
    var nameTxt = $(this).closest('tr').find('.name').text();
    var emailTxt = $(this).closest('tr').find('.email').text();
    //assign above variables text1,text2 values to other elements.
    $("#name").val( nameTxt );
    $("#email").val( emailTxt );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = [];
var count = 0;
$("#tblName").on("click", "tbody tr", function (event) {
   $(this).find("td").each(function () {
       values[count] = $(this).text();
       count++;
    });
});
```

Now values array contain all the cell values of that row
can be used like values[0] first cell value of clicked row

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code for simple example of delegate

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Striped Rows</h2>
  <p>The .table-striped class adds zebra-stripes to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>click</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
        <td>click</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
        <td>click</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").delegate("table tbody tr td:nth-child(4)", "click", function(){
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),        // Finds the closest row <tr> 
    $tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)");
     $.each($tds, function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
        var x = $(this).text();
        alert(x);
    });
    });
});
  </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

place folowing code in **header** section

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

define the table in **body** as

```
<table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Name/Nr.</th>
                <th>Street</th>
                <th>Town</th>
                <th>Postcode</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>View</th>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                 <td class="nr"><span>50</span></td>
                 <td>Some Street 1</td>
                 <td>Leeds</td>
                 <td>L0 0XX</td>
                 <td>United Kingdom</td>
                 <td><button type="button" class="btn grabId" >View</button></td>
            </tr>
            
</table>
```

then use this **script**

```
<script>
    $(".grabId").click(function() {
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
        var $siteId = $row.find(".siteId").text(); // Find the text
        alert($siteId);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just select javascript or jquery
If you don't have header column, don't minus by 1

```js
function rowClicked(element){
    var rowJavascript = element.parentNode.parentNode;
    var rowjQuery = $(element).closest("tr");
    
    var rowIndexJavascript = rowJavascript.rowIndex-1;
    var rowIndexjQuery = rowjQuery[0].rowIndex-1;
    
    console.log("rowIndexJavascript : ",rowIndexJavascript);
    console.log("rowIndexjQuery : ",rowIndexjQuery);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Row ID</th>
<th>Button</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0</td><td><button type="button"  onclick="rowClicked(this)">test1</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td><button type="button" onclick="rowClicked(this)">test2</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td><td><button type="button" onclick="rowClicked(this)">test3</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```