# Displaying popup on Click on jtable cell

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-jtable

I am displaying data in jquery UI jtbale using asp.net MVC 4.
I am facing problem in displaying  a new view on click of cell of jtable.
What i want is that when jtable load the data i have an extra column name load and  when i click on that column a popup should display the a new view containing the baisc information of that patient .Below i am sharing the images  for jtable.

Image of my jtable
   [image]

is it possible

Answer (score 1):

use an ajax call in your jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller")",
    type: "POST",
    data: { id: $(this).id }
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function (result) {
        $(".divContent").html(result);
        //pop up the partial view using overlay, dialog, whatever you prefer
    }
});
```

and on your controller have an method

```
public PartialViewResult Action(int id){
    model = //query the database 
    return PartialView("_PartialName", model);
}
```

see here for more information for getting table row id on button click  (can be link also,  just use a selector) [jQuery: Get the contents of a table row with a button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460421/jquery-get-the-contents-of-a-table-row-with-a-button-click)