# How to get value table row value using jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<?php
include "config.php";

// Fetch the data

$con = mysql_query("select * from product");
?>
<div style=" height:250px; overflow:auto;">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dTableR" id="ajxtable">
        <tr>
            <th>Jobno</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Designed by</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($con)) {
            $id       = $row['id'];
            $pcode    = $row['pcode'];
            $lproduct = $row['lproduct'];
            $mrprate  = $row['mrprate'];
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $lproduct; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mrprate; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "admin"; ?></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton1" style="width:25px;" value="+" onClick=""/>
                    <input type="button" id="delPOIbutton1" style="width:25px;" value="-" onClick=""/></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is ajax page. Below table is auto refreshed every 5 seconds.

My doubt is how to get that particular row value.

When i click table row + button, get these particular row  values, and place to index page text box and this '+' button also hide.

Kindly suggest any jquery or ajax code for adding below code.

I am new to jquery ,,anybody help me with sample code..that would help me greately. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Get the contents of a table row with a button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460421/jquery-get-the-contents-of-a-table-row-with-a-button-click)

Comment: This is not a `code my app for me` site. Identify a specific issue, document it, show what you have already tried. Then you can expect some help.

Comment: Above code is ajax page code. This table display on my index page (by using div). When i click + button above table, that particular row value (jobno,product, qty) are place to index page 3 text box. how to get the value and transfer to index page text box.

Comment: Mr.martynas , that link code is not working in ajax page. it's work only run separately.

Comment: Dont use `mysql`! use `mysqli` instead

Comment: and a query is not a connection, so the var `$con` should be `$query` or something. Its not causing errors or somerthing, its just the programming style thats incorrect

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
     $('#yourtablename tr').click(function (event) {
          alert($(this).attr('id')); //trying to alert id of the clicked row          

     });
 });
```

Above code may be help you and another solution is:

```
 $('td').click(function(){
       var row_index = $(this).parent().index();
       var col_index = $(this).index();
    });
```