# How to read dynamically generated HTML table row's td value?

Tags: jquery, html

In my application I need to enter all the input values in input controls (TextBoxes).

Then, insert these values in a table as a row, Here I was checking the redundant EmpNo values. 
The delete button will be generated dynamically along with the ID while inserting the row of the table.

Now I need to delete the row when delete button is clicked

How to select the row of a selected delete button ? and remove it from the table ?

[image]

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x34fseh3/3/)

```
$("#btnInsert").click(function () {
            var eNo = $("#txtEmpNo").val();
            var eName = $("#txtEmpName").val();
            var sal = $("#txtSalary").val();
            var deptNo = $("#txtDeptNo").val();
            var rowCnt = $("#tblBody tr").size();

            if (eNo == "" && eName == "" && sal == "" && deptNo == "") {
                alert("Enter values");
            }
            else {
                if (rowCnt == 0) {
                    $("<tr><td id='Items" + rowCnt + "'>" + eNo + "</td><td>" + eName + "</td><td>" + sal + "</td><td>" + deptNo +" <input type='button' value='Delete' id='btnDelete"+rowCnt+"'/></td></tr>").appendTo("#tblBody");
                    $("input[id^=txt]").val(""); 
                    $("input[id^=btnDelete]").bind("click", function () {
                        alert("delete button is clicked");
                    });

                }
                else {
                    var dupCount = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < rowCnt; i++) {
                        var num = $("#Items" + i).html().toString();
                        if (eNo == num) {
                            dupCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (dupCount == 0) {
                        $("<tr><td id='Items" + rowCnt + "'>" + eNo + "</td><td>" + eName + "</td><td>" + sal + "</td><td>" + deptNo + " <input type='button' value='Delete' id='btnDelete" + rowCnt + "'/></td></tr>").appendTo("#tblBody");
                        $("input[id^=txt]").val("");
                        $("input[id^=btnDelete]").bind("click", function () {
                            alert("delete button is clicked");
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Your entered EmpNo is already exists in the table !");
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: I placed code in jsfiddle, please view here http://jsfiddle.net/x34fseh3/1/

Comment: Any chance of a _working_ jsfiddle?

Comment: @3rror404 But it worked well in my local machine i.e visual studio IDE. I placed same code in the jsfiddle. But it is not working in jsfiddle.

Comment: @AstroCB Thanks for rectifying the mistakes. Please tell, Is this correct way to bind click event function while inserting row or Is there any best way to delete the row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x34fseh3/5/).

Here is the important line:

JS

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

I just used your click event to trigger the .remove().

Answer (score 0):

Generate the row and button's ID in a consistent way (like DelButton1, Row1;DelButton2, Row2, etc). Then in the delete buttons event handler, get the id of the caller, use that to figure out the id of the accompanying row, and delete that row.

Also, note that to remove an element you need to use removeChild() on the parent of that element.

Alternatively, if you have the delete button object, you can use:

```
<deleteButton>.parentNode.parentNode
```

to get the tr element (the first parentNode gets the td element the button is in, the second the tr). Note that if you have any other tags around the button before the tr, that means you need call parentNode more times.

Comment: Yes I am able to append the row to the table, Here I need to get the row of the clicked Delete button,then remove that row from the table .

Comment: That's what I'm talking about? Removing the row is equivalent to deleting the <tr> element.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is reading in the input and appending the html to the table:

```
var rowid = 0;
function addRow(empno, name, sal, deptno){
   rowid = "tableRow" + tableid;
   var row = "<tr id=rowid><td>"+ empno+"</td>"+ "<td>"+ name+"</td>"+ "<td>"+
                           sal+"</td>"+ "<td>"+deptno+"</td></tr>";
           $("tbody").append(row);
           id+=1;
     }
function removeRow(rowid){...}
```

This code adds to the table. So on input "click" you have to read in the values correctly.

Comment: Yes I did that , I need to delete the selected row when I click on delete button

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
 //=======remove dyanamic file=====//
    $(document).on("click", "#btnDelete", function () {
        $(this).closest("#YourtrID").remove();
    });
```

it's working