# How to fill input fields in form with data from row in html table I want to edit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have this HTML table with data from MySQL database and form for adding/editing rows in this table. If I add new row, everything works fine, but when I want to edit, I dont know how to pre-fill input text fields in this form. I have id of specific row saved as id of each editing button, but I dont know how to get know the ID from this clicked button. And should I have to do it with PHP or JS?

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Poradi</th>
                        <th> Jmeno</th>
                        <th> Prijmeni</th>
                        <th> Adresa</th>
                        <th> Mesto</th>
                        <th> Telefon</th>
                        <th> Email</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $db = new PDO(
                        "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xyz",
                        "xyz",
                        "xy"
                    );

                    $stmp = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user");
                    $stmp->execute();
                    $data = array();
                    while ($row = $stmp->fetch()) {
                        $data[]=($row);
                        echo "<tr>
                                <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['login'] . "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['email'] . "</td><td>";
                        $id = $row['id'];
                        echo "<a><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' id=$id></i></a></td>
                        </tr>";
                    }

                    ?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>


            </div>

            <div class="sideMenu">
                <form method="post" class="form-group" action="add.php">
                    <h1>Pridat servis</h1>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Jmeno" required autofocus>
                    <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Prijmeni" required>
                    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Adresa" required>
                    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Mesto" required>
                    <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Telefon" required>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>

                    <div class="btn-toolbar">
                        <button class="btn" type="submit">Ulozit</button>
                        <button class="btn" type="button">Zrusit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <div class="icon-close">
                    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/close.png">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution I was looking for. Advices from guys here are right as well in case it never mind you redirect from your site.

I wanted to do it dynamically with jQuery if it would be possible and I've found this solution which works for me perfect, so I share it here.

[jQuery: Get the contents of a table row with a button click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14460421/3718059)

Answer (score 0):

I was on the same page when I have started.

You should use

`echo "<a href=\"edit.php?id=".$row['id']."\"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' id=$id></i></a>`

On edit.php you will use $_GET['id'] to get the id of clicked element.

Comment: Your solution would be helpful, but I dont want to redirect or refresh website, I wanted to do that just dynamically. I've found different solution which works but anyway, thanks a lot for inspiration :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell you script whichrecord you want to edit.

Best way will be to add href to your edit anchor.

```
echo "<a href="/url/to/this/script?id=$id"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' id=$id></i></a></td>
```

Now after refresh you can get id of record you want to edit by:

```
// this way provide some base security
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

// Now get record from database (only sample call - need to build prepare statement)
$record = $database->getRecordById($id);

// After that fill form with record data
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Jmeno" value="<?php $record->name ?>" required autofocus>
```