# Disable all other checkboxes in tabular row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want all other checkboxes if one is selected. As far as I can see the code should be working (there are no console errors). What am I doing wrong?

As an added complexity this same event listener may tick other checkboxes; ideally the rows containing any of these checkboxes that become checked should also be disabled.

```js
(".chkbox").on('change', function() {

  var locked = false;
  // var for current row
  var row = $(this).closest('tr').index();

  var $checkboxes = $('#key_table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + (row + 1) + ')').find('[type=checkbox]');

  $(this).on('click', function toggleLock(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Make locked true if it was false, or vice-versa
    locked = !locked;

    // And apply that value to the 'disabled' attribute of the checkboxes
    $checkboxes.attr('disabled', locked);
  });
});
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <caption>
    <h5>Selection</h5>
  </caption>
  <tr id="9">
    <td>9.00</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" title="9" value="9" />orders</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" title="113" value="113" />placements</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" title="128" value="128" />merchandise</td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="10">
    <td>10.00</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" title="9" value="9" />transport</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" title="113" value="113" />shipping</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" title="128" value="128" />merchandise</td>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="11">
    <td>11.00</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" title="128" value="128" />merchandise</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" title="113" value="113" />shipping</td>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: @Jai but people can't un-select radio buttons ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460421/jquery-get-the-contents-of-a-table-row-with-a-button-click check it

Comment: @stumbler the idea seems to be check only one option so I felt radios would be a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(".chkbox").click(function(){
    var currentObj = $(this);
    $(this)
        .closest("tr")
        .find(".chkbox").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $(currentObj).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jslight/48z0vLxw/)

Comment: Getting a "ReferenceError: update_key_type is not defined" error

Comment: added fiddle check it

Comment: What's the need to create the variable `currentObj `?

Answer (score 2):

In this demo you can also uncheck and that action will enable each checkboxes in a row

working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/darxide/vpvaseL0/

```
$('body').on('change' , 'tr input' , function () {

var count_checked = 0;

$(this).parent().parent().find('input:checked').each(function() {
    count_checked++
})

if(count_checked > 0){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled' , true)
    })
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled')
} else {
    $(this).parent().parent().find("input").removeAttr('disabled')
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.closest().siblings().find().prop()` method in this case. Another suggestion is to use group radios:

```
$(".chkbox").on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest("td").siblings("td").find(":checkbox").prop("disabled", this.checked);
});
```

Here `this.checked` returns boolean value. If checked `true` and unchecked then `false`.

---

The issue seems to me that the way you have written your code that tells to bind the click event on currently clicked check box.

---

```js
    $(".chkbox").on('change', function() {
        $(this).closest("td").siblings("td").find(":checkbox").prop("disabled", this.checked);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <caption>
    <h5>Selection</h5>
  </caption>
  <tr id="9">
    <td>9.00</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" title="9" value="9" />orders</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" title="113" value="113" />placements</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" title="128" value="128" />merchandise</td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="10">
    <td>10.00</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" title="9" value="9" />transport</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" title="113" value="113" />shipping</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" title="128" value="128" />merchandise</td>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="11">
    <td>11.00</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" title="128" value="128" />merchandise</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" title="113" value="113" />shipping</td>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if checked one checkbox in a row the selected one will also be disabled?

Comment: @RakeshSadhula good point. Ideally the selected one should not be disabled to allow users to unselect that option. The disabling is merely client side validation.

Comment: @Stumbler Did you tried this code. See i have added a sample below. With a single chain you can get the desired result. on the day i was on mobile so i wasn't able to put a sample demo. now you can see that that is perfectly working.

Comment: @RakeshSadhula How come is that? Did you tried this code. I have added a sample you can see how is it going.

Comment: @Jai i was asking if checked then current will be disable or not your code works fine.

Comment: @RakeshSadhula _if checked one checkbox in a row the selected one will also be disabled?_ where did you say that?

Comment: @Jai that was my question SO answered that in above comment

Comment: @Jai this is a good answer (and that's why I upvoted it). However ultimately I ended up using  Rakesh's answer.