# Get clicked button table row values to update the database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a web project there i am getting data from database and show them in a table/tables to edit and update the database. Table structure is same. There may be multiple tables or just only one table. It is a vary.

Each table row has a button to send updated data to the database. My problem is I cannot identify the button.Which button am i clicking. After i change the data i want to click the button and update that row in the database.

My code...

I am looping the section according to the field called agenda. Each agenda has a table. So there may be one agenda or multiple. Each table has a different ID. I  increment table IDs.

```
<?php 

    $mCount = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($agenda_result)) {
    $myCount = ++$mCount;

  ?>

  <section class="color">

      <h1 class="agenda_head"> <?php echo trim($row['agenda_name']); ?> </h1>

      <?php 

      $agnd_id = $row['agenda_id'];

      $get_tbl_data = $db->prepare("SELECT distinct mType, mDivision, discuss_point, mAction, statDate, dueDate, status, user_tbl.fName FROM meeting_i_tbl inner join user_tbl on meeting_i_tbl.responsible_id = user_tbl.user_id WHERE meeting_i_tbl.meeting_id = ? and meeting_i_tbl.agenda_id = ?");
      $get_tbl_data->bind_param("ss",$selected_meet_id,$agnd_id);
      $get_tbl_data->execute();
      $tbl_data_result = $get_tbl_data->get_result();    

      ?>

      <center><table class="responstable" id="responstable_tbl<?php echo $myCount; ?>" name="res_tbl_name<?php echo $myCount; ?>"> 
      <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Division</th>
      <th>Discuss Points</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th>Start Date</th>
      <th>Due Date</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Res: Person</th>
      <th></th>
      </tr>

      <?php


      while ($row_res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tbl_data_result)) {


      ?>

      <tr>
      <td> <?php echo trim($row_res['mType']); ?> </td>
      <td> <?php echo trim($row_res['mDivision']); ?> </td>
      <td> <?php echo trim($row_res['discuss_point']); ?> </td>
      <td> <?php echo trim($row_res['mAction']); ?> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="datepickerClass" value="<?php echo trim($row_res['statDate']); ?>" placeholder="Meeting Date"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="datepickerClass" value="<?php echo trim($row_res['dueDate']); ?>" placeholder="Due Date"/></td>

      <td class="select_op_div">

      <select name="status" class="select_option">
        <option<?php if ($row_res['status'] == "1"): ?> id="1" selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Pending</option>
        <option<?php if ($row_res['status'] == "2"): ?> id="2" selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>On Going</option>
        <option<?php if ($row_res['status'] == "3"): ?> id="3" selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Completed</option>
        <option<?php if ($row_res['status'] == "4"): ?> id="4" selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>-</option>
      </select>

      </td>

      <td class="nr"> <?php echo trim($row_res['fName']); ?> </td>
      <td>
      <form action='detailform.php' method='POST'>
      <input type='submit' onclick="row_update()" name='btn_update' value='up'/>
      </form>
      </td>
      </tr>

      <?php

      }   

      ?>
      </table></center>

  </section>

<div style="height: 25px;">
</div>

<?php

}

mysqli_close($db);
$myCount = 0;
?>
```

`row_update()` is the function of the button click.

For testing I tried with this but no luck. I just only want to get all the button clicked row values. I can do the update.

```
function row_update(){

var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
var $tds = $row.find("td");
$.each($tds, function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});

}
```

I tried with this method also.

```
   $("#responstable_tbl tr").click(function(){

    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460421/jquery-get-the-contents-of-a-table-row-with-a-button-click

This should help you getting the rows.

Comment: it worked........

Comment: so yay? '111111111111111'

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the row id in onclick function like function row_update(); 
function row_update(rowid){
Alert(rowid);
Your update data id is here
});
}
Sorry but my English is not good.