# How to Add button to each row in a table and on click of particular row button only that button has to hide using html jQuery php

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is my HTML table with all the buttons on click of one button show another button immediately in the same row this is  my code but I don't know how I need to make this work

```
<table id="example" class="stripe row-border order-column" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Drawing</th>
<th style="display:none">Overview</th>
<th>Stage</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>BW101-01</td>
<td>1</td>
<td><button type="button" class="clarify">Clarify</button>
    <button type="button" class="allott">Allott</button>
    <p id="satge3">Started / Paused</p>
    <button type="button" class="correctit">correctit</button>
    <button type="button" class="send">send</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>BW102-02</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>  <button type="button" class="clarify">Clarify</button>
      <button type="button" class="allott">Allott</button>
      <p id="satge3">Started / Paused</p>
      <button type="button" class="correctit">correctit</button>
      <button type="button" class="send">send</button></td>
</tr>                 
</tbody>
</table>
```

on click of the one button in table show another button which row button is clicked

This is my JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();
         **var Stage = 1; //i get this from database**
        alert(Stage);

        if (Stage == 1) {
          $(".allott").hide();
          $(".clarify").show();
          $(".satge3").hide();
          $(".correctit").hide();
          $(".send").hide();
        } else if (Stage == 2) {
          $(".allott").show();
          $(".clarify").hide();
          $(".satge3").hide();
          $(".correctit").hide();
          $(".send").hide();
        } 


          $('.clarify').on('click', function(e) {
          $(".allott").show();
          $(".clarify").hide();
          $(".satge3").hide();
          $(".correctit").hide();
          $(".send").hide();
        });


});
```

something like this I want to achieve
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taraVed/mujy5fw8/14/)

Comment: Where is the pause button in your code? Anyway once you add the second button you can use `$(this).hide(); $(this).parent().find('.pause').show()`

Comment: `id` must be unique on a page.  You have multiple sets of buttons with the same `id`, eg 2x with `id="clarify"`, etc...

Comment: Use CSS classes instead of IDs, and then `$(this)` to identify which button was clicked, then traverse with eg `find()` to find other buttons by class in that row.  Eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460421/get-the-contents-of-a-table-row-with-a-button-click

Comment: YES if i use class also am not able to change buttons accordingly one after another

Comment: @Don'tPanic plz look into this

Comment: Look at what? Your question shows duplicate ids, and the linked duplicate describes why that won't work and how to solve it. If you've tried something else, edit your question, show your new attempt, and describe what happens now.

Comment: In scrip how i can take all the row stage id and give condition i thing am doing mistake there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235097/discussion-between-thejashwini-l-and-dont-panic).

Comment: I don't see any updated code other than switching to classes.  Did you read through [the answers in the question I linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460421/get-the-contents-of-a-table-row-with-a-button-click)?  Did you try anything suggested there?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option. Re-use the same button and change the text, you can process different actions in the javascript based on it's state

```js
$('.start').on('click', function(e) {
  let isPaused = $(this).text().toLowerCase() === "pause";
  if (isPaused) {
    $(this).text('Start');
  } else {
    $(this).text('Pause');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Drawing</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Drawing1</td>
      <td><button class="start">Start</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drawing2</td>
      <td><button class="start">Start</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry but i want to achieve like above question @Kinglish