# Append text to class when id changes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to append text when some id changes.

```html
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <input name="stime" type="text" class="form-control" id="stime" placeholder="00:00" required maxlength="5" />
    <span class="form-control-feedback"></span>
</div>
```

When `stime` changes, I want to append a text to the `form-control-feedback` class.

This is my script, but nothing changes.

```js
$("#stime").change(function (e) {
    var time = $("#stime").val();

    $("#stime").find(".form-control-feedback").append("* Check Format Time (HH:mm)");
});
```

thank you, it solved.

Comment: ```$(".form-control-feedback").append("* Check Format Time (HH:mm)");```

Comment: @Don'tPanic That's not the issue here, the asker is trying to use `.find()` to get a sibling element.

Comment: @Joundill If that is really what the OP is trying to do, then there are 2 issues here - the dup I linked addresses one of them.  You said the same thing in your answer ... ?

Comment: If you are really trying to do this for multiple sets of `input`s (this seems unlikely since you have an ID here), the best way IMO is to traverse *up* the DOM to the closest enclosing block element, and then search *down* to the element you want to change.  Eg: `$('input').on('change', function() { $(this).closest('.col-sm-1').find('form-control-feedback').text('* Check Format Time (HH:mm)'); });`. A good reference for the general approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460421/get-the-contents-of-a-table-row-with-a-button-click

Comment: *Typo missing `.` - `find('.form-control-feedback')`

Comment: @Don'tPanic It's true that `.text()` works better than `.append()` in OP's case, but that's not really what the question is about. `.append()` will also technically work (just only the first time)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `.siblings()` instead of `.find()` because the `.form-control-feedback` element isn't a child of `#stime`, but instead a sibling.

You're also probably looking for `.text()`, not `.append()`

```js
$("#stime").change(function (e) {
  var time = $("#stime").val();
  $("#stime").siblings(".form-control-feedback").text("* Check Format Time (HH:mm)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-1">
  <input name="stime" type="text" class="form-control" id="stime" placeholder="00:00" required maxlength="5">
  <span class='form-control-feedback'></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following

```
$("#stime").change(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".form-control-feedback").append("* Check Format Time (HH:mm)");
});
```

but since the input is unique by id I'd rather assign the id to the span as well. Then

```
$("#stime").change(function () {
    $("#form-control-feedback").append("* Check Format Time (HH:mm)");
});
```

or

```
$("#stime").change(function () {
    $("#form-control-feedback").text("* Check Format Time (HH:mm)");
});
```

if you don't want to append but rather replace